# AWK: how to clean bibtex files?

Tags: awk, bibtex

I have a bibtex file (exported from Zotero) and I want to clean it by removing particular fields.

As an example, removing the *file* field from the following entry:

```
@inproceedings{sridharan_fast_2008,
    title = {Fast {Rates} for {Regularized} {Objectives}.},
    urldate = {2014-03-26},
    booktitle = {{NIPS}},
    author = {Sridharan, Karthik and Shalev-Shwartz, Shai and Srebro, Nathan},
    year = {2008},
    pages = {1545--1552},
    file = {3400-fast-rates-for-regularized-objectives.pdf:/home/johnros/.zotero/zotero/66g0wvis.default/zotero/storage/6ND67P5F/3400-fast-rates-for-regularized-objectives.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `grep` quite easily:

```
grep -v "^\s*file =" bibtext.txt
```

The trailing comma on the previous record should not be a problem... [see here](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/).

Or, if you are really keen on `awk`:

```
awk '!/file = /' bibtext.txt
```

Comment: I appreciated mostly the link to `bibtex`'s documentation

Comment: I *guess* the comma(`,`) on the line `pages=...`  should get removed too, so that we can make the output still "format conformed" ?

Comment: @Kent - According to the link I included, it should not matter - I guess it depends if you are a purist or a pragmatist :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `bibtex` format, if there is some tool, which providing better editing on those format, you should pick those tools.

If you would like using `awk` to handle it, here is one gnu awk one-liner:

```
awk -v RS=',\n\\s*file\\s*=\\s[^\\n]*' '7' file
```

Basically, it is just playing with `RS` variable, to remove the `file=` line also the previous ending comma `","`, so that keep the generated output still being valid bibtex format. (I hope it is).

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
@inproceedings{sridharan_fast_2008,
    title = {Fast {Rates} for {Regularized} {Objectives}.},
    urldate = {2014-03-26},
    booktitle = {{NIPS}},
    author = {Sridharan, Karthik and Shalev-Shwartz, Shai and Srebro, Nathan},
    year = {2008},
    pages = {1545--1552},
    file = {3400-fast-rates-for-regularized-objectives.pdf:/home/johnros/.zotero/zotero/66g0wvis.default/zotero/storage/6ND67P5F/3400-fast-rates-for-regularized-objectives.pdf:application/pdf}
}

kent$  awk -v RS=',\n\\s*file\\s*=\\s[^\\n]*' '7' f
@inproceedings{sridharan_fast_2008,
    title = {Fast {Rates} for {Regularized} {Objectives}.},
    urldate = {2014-03-26},
    booktitle = {{NIPS}},
    author = {Sridharan, Karthik and Shalev-Shwartz, Shai and Srebro, Nathan},
    year = {2008},
    pages = {1545--1552}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but for those who still find this: there's an extension to Zotero ([Zotero Better BibTeX](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex)) that allows you to do this inside Zotero itself. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this extension.